# How can I identify common elements in at least 2 out of 5 tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have 5 tables, what join functions should I be using if I want to find elements in a single column that occur in AT LEAST 2 out of the 5 tables?, ie: discarding only those elements that occur in a single table.

Would the code be similar if I wanted to find common elements in AT LEAST 3/5 tables?

(I'm using MS Access)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% positive I understand your question, but I think you can use `UNION ALL` for this:

```
select yourcol
from (
  select distinct yourcol from t1
  union all
  select distinct yourcol from t2
  union all
  select distinct yourcol from t3
  union all
  select distinct yourcol from t4
  union all
  select distinct yourcol from t5
) t
group by id
having count(*) >= 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1379/1)

Then you can change `>= 2` to whatever number you want.

BTW -- if the column in question doesn't contain duplicates, you can remove `distinct` from the subquery.

Comment: I tried inputting this into access, (where my table names are "ww" "xx" and "yy" and my column name is "hit"SELECT hit
from (
'select distinct hit from ww
union all
select distinct hit from xx
union all
select distinct hit from yy
union all
) t
group by hit
having count (*) >=2' but I get an syntax error: "Incomplete query clause." Any idea where I went wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user2593616 -- remove the last `union all`.  The subquery should end in `yy)`.

Comment: @user2593616 -- np, glad I could help!